# Python Socket - Server Stop after receive only one message

Tags: python, sockets, apscheduler, python-sockets

firstly sorry for my bad english (I'm French) because I'm trying to not use Google Translate.

So, my problem is in the following set of server.py and `client.py`. Just a client that send every 10 seconds a message with a incremental counter on the `server.py`. I write this script to check if my university work server "live" or "die" after my logout (and for my training).

`server.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 1602

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind(('localhost', PORT))

while True:
        socket.listen(5)
        client, address = socket.accept()
        print(f"{address} connected")

        response = client.recv(1024)
        print(response.decode())

print("Close")
client.close()
socket.close()
```

`client.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 1602

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
print(f"Connection on {PORT}")

timeCount = 0

def some_job():
    global timeCount
    timeCount += 1

    print(f"Send N°{timeCount}")
    string = f'Schedule Transmission N°{timeCount}'
    socket.send(f"Schedule Transmission N°{timeCount}".encode())

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(some_job, 'interval', seconds=5)
scheduler.start()

print("Close")
socket.close()
```

The problem is that the server side print only (and probably receive only) the first message/first transmission. So, not a problem of encodage and the connexion seems to exist even after the first message print.
I understand well the code in itself. I don't see what's the problem. There is any exception or error when running.

Can someone help me, please?

Cordially

Comment: You need a nested loop to keep reading messages until it gets EOF.

Comment: You can also use multi-threading. When a client connects, spawn a thread to process that socket while the original thread waits for new connections.

Comment: @lechat-marcellin You should move socket.listen() to outside of infinite loop.  It is enough to be called once to mark the socket for listening.

Comment: @sigkilled Thanks. Even if that was not the problem in my code, it's interesting to know that for my training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only needed to change your server code. I added multithreading. Now multible clients can connect to the server without blocking the entire process.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
import threading

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 1602

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind(('localhost', PORT))

def handle_client(client, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    connected = True
    while connected:
        response = client.recv(1024)
        if response:
            print(f"[{addr}] {response.decode()}")

    client.close()
    

while True:
    socket.listen()
    client, addr = socket.accept()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client, addr))
    thread.start()
```

Comment: Thank you. This code indeed work very well and I will use it. However, isn't there a way to solve the problem and achieve the same result without Multithreading and just Socket? It's just for my knowledge and my training.